# "Forbidden to" vs "Forbidden from"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

Which sounds better (and where do you live?) I am American, and I think "forbidden from" sounds better, although both "forbidden to" and "forbidden from" are considered standard usage.

"The banks were forbidden from making any more subprime loans."
vs.
"The banks were forbidden to make any more subprime loans."

Answer (score 22):

Use "to" with the infinitive verb form, "from" with a gerund.

> You two are forbidden to date each other.
>
> You two are forbidden from dating each other.

Comment: What is the difference in meaning of those two?

Comment: @Robusto : No difference in meaning but only on the right form....

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, the first one is correct.

"The banks were forbidden from making any more subprime loans."

Comment: Rory, I disagree. If you need "from" change forbid for another verb here : ban, hinder, keep, prevent, prohibit & stop.

Answer (score -1):

I read that expressions of prevention, prohibition, banning, exclusion or stopping actions take gerund-participle complements in PPs headed by **from**. The verbs are : ban, hinder, keep, prevent, prohibit & stop (*cf.* Cambridge Grammar, last ed. p. 835 *in fine*.)

I guess to "forbid from" could derive from such forms like : "To forbid [access] **from** that time/place/limit **to** this time/place/limit".

However it is not *to forbid from* (...) but *to forbid **to***, even if in AmE you - not I - could say it.

Answer (score -2):

you wouldn't say "I forbid you from leaving," rather than "I forbid you to leave." therefore I say leave out from.